# Sorting .txt files

Tags: python

I am trying to make the 'scores' section of my code sort it self in ascending order, and the print the 5 highest values. I've tried using panda but it doesn't help. can anyone help?

```
x = 0

Name = [None]*1000
Score = [0]*100

text_file = open("txt.Scores.txt","a")


def write_in_file():
    global text_file
    text_file.write(Name[x])
    text_file.write("\n")
    text_file.write(Score[x])
    text_file.write("\n")
    text_file.write("\n")
    text_file.close()
    text_file = open("txt.Scores.txt","a")


for i in name:    
    Name[x] = input("Username:")
    Score[x] = input("Score:")
    write_in_file()
    print(Score)
    x += 1
```

when i run the code, it gives me an output that looks like this:

```
Username:Jonny
Score:15
['15', 0, 0, 0, 0]


Username:Max
Score:15 
['15', '15', 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and the text file looks like this:

Jonny
15

Max
15

I am trying to get it to print the 5 highest scores only

Comment: Please share a sample of your text file which you are reading and also the expected output.

Comment: You don't sort anywhere, you are just writing out empty strings and zeroes.

Comment: your code currently has no logic written to "Sort" anything as far as i can tell. try to search around for ["how to sort a list"](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort). also, look at the pythonic way to open a file. additionally, do not modify the same list you are iterating through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store Name and its corresponding score, and print the highest score values.

```
X = {}
with open("txt.Scores.txt", 'w+') as score:
    while len(X) < 10:
        Name = input("Username: ")
        Score = int(input("Score: "))
        X[Score] = Name
        print(Name + '\t\t' + str(Score), file=score)

Y = sorted(list(X.keys()), reverse=True)        
y = range(0, len(Y))
Scores = [Y[i] for i in y[:5]]
print(Scores)
print([X[i] for i in Scores])
```

This code will get 10 names and scores as input, store them in `'txt.Scores.txt'` and print 5 highest scores stored in a list, and their corresponding names in another list.

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Accept the answer if it worked for you, so that the question doesn't remain unanswered

Answer (score 0):

you have not defined `name` which you use in your for loop,you should use `while True:`instead, then make an empty list name to fill it depending on the input.

Answer (score 0):

At first read about file's descriptors [If you don’t use “with”, when does Python close files? The answer is: It depends.](http://blog.lerner.co.il/dont-use-python-close-files-answer-depends/)

You can use python's sort as:

```
with open('txt.Scores.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    data = [int(line.strip()) for line in data if line.strip() != str() and all(i.isdigit() for i in line.strip())]
    print sorted(data, reverse=True)
```

Or [GNU sort](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) ass executed command with specific keys.